# Symbolic calculation with generators and relations

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, tensors, algebra

Is it possible to do the following in Mathematica:

Define an algebra $A$ via generators and relations and multiply some tensors in $A\otimes A$ (and of course simplify the relations via the relations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edit.* Based on the comments, here is a more concrete answer to what I think you'd like. My previous answer can be found below.

**Defining a ring symbolically.** Let's consider some ring (or algebra) generated by symbols $g_i^\pm$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Actually I'm not going to specify $n$ in the following as I don't think there's any need for it.

First of all let's make these generators look nice, based on [your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165927),

```
Format[g[i_, 1]] := Subsuperscript[g, i, "+"]
Format[g[i_, -1]] := Subsuperscript[g, i, "-"]
```

Next we are going to set up the product. Let us use `CenterDot`, which can be conveniently entered as `[esc].[esc]` and by default looks like `•`. Say we want this product to be additive, unital, and associative:

```
CenterDot[X___, Y_Plus, Z___] := CenterDot[X, #, Z] & /@ Y (* additivity *)
CenterDot[] = 1;
CenterDot[X_] := X
CenterDot[X___, 1, Y___] := CenterDot[X, Y] (* unital*) 
SetAttributes[CenterDot, Flat] (* associativity *)
```

Here the second and third line ensure that we don't get stuck with a product of zero or one generator when we pull out the unit (identity element) `1` from a product.

We might further want to implement some multiplication rules. Let's say, for example, I want to make all generators anticommutative, $g_i^s g_j^r = -g_j^r g_i^s$ (where $s,r=\pm$) and have $g_i^- = (g_i^+)^{-1}$ 
each other's inverse. We're going to implement this as replacement rules, so that you can choose wheter or not you'd like to use these rules. (As I mention in my older answer below, you can also build these rules into the definition of `CenterDot` to get automatic simplifications, just like we automatically implemented additivity etc above. I choose not to do so for the multiplication rules.)

```
reorder[expr_] := expr //. CenterDot[X___, g[j_, r_], g[i_, s_], Y___] /; Not@OrderedQ@{j, i} -> -CenterDot[X, g[i, s], g[j, r],Y]
cancelinverses[expr_] := expr //. CenterDot[X___, g[i_, s_], g[j_, r_], Y___] /; i == j && s == -r -> CenterDot[X, Y]
```

These rules reduce expressions to ensure that in the result the $g_i^\pm$ will be ordered by increasing subscripts. For example, you can try

```
g[1, 1]\[CenterDot]g[2, 1] // reorder (* already ordered, so nothing happens *)
g[i, 1]\[CenterDot]g[j, 1] // reorder (* likewise, where the ordering is now alphabetical *)
g[i, 1]\[CenterDot]g[i, -1] // reorder (* likewise *)
g[j, -1]\[CenterDot]g[i, 1] // reorder (* reordered, yielding a sign *)
g[i, 1]\[CenterDot]g[k, -1]\[CenterDot]g[j, -1] // reorder (* likewise *)
g[k, 1]\[CenterDot]g[i, -1]\[CenterDot]g[j, -1] // reorder (* likewise, now yielding two signs, so a plus *)
g[i, 1]\[CenterDot]g[i, -1] // cancelinverses (* = 1 *)
g[i, 1]\[CenterDot]g[j, -1]\[CenterDot]g[i, -1] // reorder // cancelinverses (* = -g[j,-1] *)
```

Note that `cancelinverses` decreases the number of elements in the product, so the preceding examples use the fact that above we set `CenterDot[]=1;` and `CenterDot[X_]:=X`.

**Defining the tensor products of this ring.** Next we turn to tensor products. We're going to do this by defining one more product, which we will do just like before. Let us use `CircleTimes`, which can be entered as `[esc]c*[esc]` and appropriately looks like $\otimes$.

Give it all the properties that the tensor product should have, similar to what we did for `CenterDot` above. Let's say we want the tensor product to be linear over scalars, where the latter means anything not involving the generators. For this we set

```
CentralQ[expr_] := FreeQ[expr, g]
```

to check if something is a scalar, and then define

```
CircleTimes[X___, Y_Plus, Z___] := CircleTimes[X, #, Z] & /@ Y (* additive *)
CircleTimes[X___, s_?CentralQ Y_, Z___] := s CircleTimes[X, Y, Z] (* linear *)

CircleTimes[] = 1;
CircleTimes[X_] := X (* avoid getting stuck with a single CircleTimes[X] after the following *)
CircleTimes[X___, s_?CentralQ , Y___] := s CircleTimes[X, Y] (* unital*)

SetAttributes[CircleTimes, Flat] (* associativity *)
```

Note that the unital property is now implemented for any scalar multiple of 1.
Then things like

```
(g[i,1] - g[j,-1])\[CircleTimes](g[k,-1] + 2)
```

will simplify correctly.

The final step is to extend the product given by `CenterDot` to this tensor product:

```
CenterDot[X_CircleTimes, Y_CircleTimes] := Inner[CenterDot, X, Y, CircleTimes]
```

Try it out for

```
(g[i,1]\[CircleTimes]g[j,-1])\[CenterDot](g[k,-1]\[CircleTimes]g[l,1])
(g[i,1]\[CircleTimes]g[j,-1])\[CenterDot](g[k,-1]\[CircleTimes]g[l,1])\[CenterDot](g[i,-1]\[CircleTimes]g[n,-1]) // reorder // cancelinverses
(g[i,1]\[CircleTimes]g[j,-1])\[CenterDot](g[k,-1]\[CircleTimes](g[l,1] + g[m,1]))
```

---

*Old answer.*

Yes, that's possible. Here is one way. First we specify the generators we want to work with:

```
NClist = {g1, ..., gN};
CentralQ[expr_] := And @@ (FreeQ[expr, #]& /@ NClist)
```

The function `CentralQ` checks whether an expression does not involve any of the generators.

Next we define a general noncommutative product `CenterDot` (with in-built shorthand `[esc].[esc]`) that is multilinear (over scalars = anything not in `NClist`), unital and associative:

```
CenterDot[X___, Y_Plus, Z___] := CenterDot[X, #, Z] & /@ Y (* additivity *)
CenterDot[X___, s_?CentralQ Y_, Z___] := s CenterDot[X, Y, Z] (* extract scalars *)
CenterDot[X_] := X (* avoid getting stuck with a single CenterDot[X] after the folowing *)
CenterDot[X___, s_?CentralQ, Z___] := s CenterDot[X, Z] (* unital *)
SetAttributes[CenterDot, {Flat}] (* associativity *)
```

You can now implement the relations in two ways:

- by directly giving further definitions for CenterDot, so that all rules will be applied automatically, or
- by defining lists of replacement rules, so that you can implement the relations by hand (once using `/.`, or until you've exhausted them using `//.`).

Which works better depends on the context; of course you can mix the two too. I tend to prefer the latter, so that you can keep track of what is going on; for example you might divide the relations over several lists, and choose to apply one type of relations only, etc.

See also the documentation of `NonCommutativeMultiply`; I prefer `CenterDot` for aesthetical reasons only.

---

I learned the trick of defining an `CentralQ`, which allows one to define e.g. an algebra over functions, from Marius de Leeuw.

Comment: One question if that is ok for you: How would I define the addition and scalar multiplication? Or I don't have to? The relations I'll need involve e.g. the '+'.

Comment: They are implemented in the definition of `CenterDot` above: for example, the first line there says that X•(Y1+Y2+...)•Z = X•Y1•Z + X•Y2•Z + ... for any choice of X, Y1, Y2, ..., Z (including no X or no Z). (I use a lot of shorthands there to implement this, but it's really just that.) Likewise for scalar multiplication: the second line says X•(s Y)•Z= s X•Y•Z, and the fourth line X•s•Z= s X•Z whenever s is a scalar, i.e. not explicitly in the list `NClist`

Comment: So there are three components in the function CenterDot because you implement e.g. right and left distributivity at the same time? How would I implement the relation $g_ig_j=-g_jg_i$? My main problem is: In my example I don't know how many generators I have. There is a natural $N$ which can be anything and I have $g_1,...,g_N$ as generators. If I write it as you like $NClist=\{g1,...gN\}$ then Mathematica complains. I could write $NClist=\{g1,g2,g3,g4\}$ but I want to work with a specific $N$. Besides. if I type e.g. $(g1+g2).g3$ how can I get Mathematica to produce $g1.g2+g2.g3$?

Comment: Yes, the first line has three arguments for that reason. I guess that typically you'd want to use such (anti)commutation rules to ensure that all elements will be ordered with the subscripts increasing to the right. I don't have time now but will expand my answer to explain how to achieve that tomorrow or so.

Comment: And what does the `Plus` in `Y_Plus`? That was not exactly my point, it is just one out of four relations I want to implement. You already said that this will go with centerdot but I do not know how. Remember my aim to define that algebra in order to compute later some tensors in $A\otimes A\otimes A$.

Comment: That's standard Mma lingo. It means that Y is of the form Y1+... . If you don't want additivity to be implemented automatically you should remove that line, and can define a replacement rule to implement this manually. (Again, I'll get back the latter some other time soon.)

Comment: Alright, everything seems to work if I set e.g. `NClist={a,b,c,d,e}`. But I have $2N$ generators $g^{\pm}_i$ for $i=1,...,N$ and $N>0$ arbitrary. Besides I want to multiply tensors, that is e.g. $(g^{+}_i\otimes g^{-}_j)\cdot (g^{+}_i\otimes g^{-}_j)=g^{+}_i g^+_i\otimes g^{-}_j g^-_j$ and relations for the latter one should be applied.

Comment: I hope you won't forget me, still exited for your reply :)

Comment: Of course, I am happy enough that you are planing to help me. Just wanted to be sure that I don't wait for no reason :)

Comment: That's very nice, thank you! The reorder doesn't work, if there is a scalar involved, right? And how would I implement a rule such as $g⁴=1$?

Comment: I would have thought of `cancelg[expr_] := 
 expr //. CenterDot[X___, g⁴, Y___] -> CenterDot[X, Y]` but that seems not to work.

Comment: I think the reorder will also work when there is a scalar involved as that will automatically be pulled out. That is, at least for the tensor product; in the above I did not make the ring multiplication linear. If you want to start from an algebra instead of a ring just implement linearity of `CenterDot` as for `CircleTimes` (and update the implementation of the unital property too). As for $g^4=1$ you have to explicitly use four neighbouring arguments equal to `g`. (You can also first modify CenterDot to collect equal `g`s into `Power[g[i,s],n]`s.)