# Define trace-like function (e.g. cyclically invariant) involving operators without built-in meaning

Tags: symbolic, syntax, algebraic-manipulation, built-in-symbols

I am interested in defining a function, say $\mathrm{Tra}$, that imply operators without build-in meaning, say it involves products with the $\cdot$ (`Esc . Esc`), not assumed commuatative.

I want to mimic a trace for it, the main property being cyclic invariance, which I expect to use to simplify expressions. Now I face a syntax problem: the last two operators being the same, as is in general, when one wants to impose some invariance.

```
esq[A_CenterDot] := RotateLeft@A (*rotates to the CenterDot-product*)
Tra[A_Plus] :=Tra[#] & /@ A (*make Tra additive*)
Tra[A_CenterDot] := Tra[esq[A]]
```

Second line I've learnt from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165506/symbolic-calculation-with-generators-and-relations/165511#165511) by Jules Lamers, mutatis mutandis.

With last command I was expecting $ \mathrm{Tra}(x\cdot y\cdot y\cdot x\cdot y\cdot x) $ to yield $  \mathrm{Tra}(x\cdot x \cdot y\cdot y\cdot x\cdot y)$ (with only one left shift, but see below the aimed lexicographic order).

But this of course gives a loop instead. In general,

- how does one correct this?
- if possible: how to deal with situations when "the two *last* arrows of the commutative diagram are the same operation"?
- is there an way out to defining relations at the level of the algebra just before evaluating this "trace"? What is meant is: assuming that $\mathrm{Tra}: A \to \mathbb k$, for any $n$, here there is a commuting pentagon (joining the first and last $A^n$ at the same node)

$A^n \stackrel{left-shift}{\to} A^n \stackrel{\cdot}{\to} A \stackrel{Tra}{\to} \mathbb k\stackrel{Tra}{\leftarrow } A  \stackrel{\cdot}{\leftarrow}  A^n  $

**Edit**: After the comment(s): I wish the routine to stop, say, after the lexicographic-like order is reached. All `x` before `y` and the highest power of `x` showing up first, independently of what happens thereafter. So, *inside the Tra-operator*:

- $ x \cdot y\cdot x \cdot x \to  x\cdot x \cdot x \cdot y  $  (cyclicity allows here to group all the `x` together)
- $ y \cdot y\cdot y \cdot x \to  x\cdot y \cdot y\cdot y  $
- $ x\cdot y \cdot x\cdot y\cdot y \cdot x \cdot x \to x \cdot x \cdot x\cdot y \cdot x\cdot y\cdot y  $   (this cannot be tested with `OrderedQ`, will almost always false)

Output example is then:

$\mathrm{Tra}[ y \cdot y\cdot y \cdot x +  x\cdot y \cdot y\cdot y ]  \to  2\mathrm{Tra}[x\cdot y \cdot y\cdot y]$

since the second line above makes Tra additive, but need not be. It suffices that 
$\mathrm{Tra}[ y \cdot y\cdot y \cdot x]$ is replaced by $ \mathrm{Tra}[x\cdot y \cdot y\cdot y]$ in order to simplify.

The issue with the lexicographic for the non-commutative product order is that the test in the given answer will be always false, unless there is no interlaced `y`'s and `x`'s, but that's the exception.

Comment: Obviously the definitions you gave lead to infinite cycling. What exactly should be the stopping condition? That is, “it should apply `RotateLeft` IF ...” or “it should *stop applying* `RotateLeft` IF ...”. You say something about “arrows in the commutative diagram” but I don’t know how to relate that to your expressions. In other words, you show the desired output for the `Tra` sample expression. Can you explain why that should be the desired output and not, say, one that was rotated twice, or not rotated at all?

Comment: I hope is slightly clearer now. I didn't want to sound like a wish list, given that my programming skills are poor. But if is relevant, I should have added it.

Comment: Still unclear... Why not giving a few examples and the desired output.

Comment: @yarchik Ok, I added it. I also made Tra additive, in order for the example to make sense.

Comment: your stopping condition does not rule out infinite loops: check `OrderedQ[RotateLeft[ 
    x\[CenterDot]y\[CenterDot]y\[CenterDot]x\[CenterDot]y\[CenterDot]\
x, #]] & /@ Range[6]`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
ClearAll[esq, Tra]

esq[A_CenterDot] :=  NestWhile[RotateLeft, A, Not @* OrderedQ, 1, Length[A] - 1]

Tra[Y_Plus] := Tra[#] & /@ Y

Tra[A_CenterDot] := esq @ A
```

***Examples:***

```
Tra[x·y·y·x·y·x]
```

> ```
>  x·x·y·y·x·y
> ```

```
Tra[x·y·y·y]
```

> ```
>  x·y·y·y
> ```

```
 Tra[y·x·y·y·y]
```

> ```
>   x·y·y·y·y
> ```

```
Tra[y·y·y·x +  x·y·y·y]
```

> ```
>  2 x·y·y·y
> ```

Comment: Great. The only problem is that `Tra[A_CenterDot] := esq@A` only makes the lexicographic order. I want that under `Tra` the lexicographic order holds. So I naively added `Tra` as before, to the end of the code `Tra[A_CenterDot] := Tra[esq@A]`, and that gives loops. Still your solution manages the cyclic permutations and is great.

Comment: Which is my fault, since I poorly stated also a condition: it is the order on a circle what  matters, so the `x`'s are grouped acoording to the highest power on the circle. My bad.