# Alternatives to NumericQ that allow symbols to be considered numeric

Tags: numerics, symbolic, symbols

I am writing a program in which I am using NumericQ. I am trying to allow symbols to also be considered Numeric, so I have been using `NumericQ[a]=True` for all of the symbols that I want to be numeric. However, this messes with the functionality of Solve so that I have to write `NumericQ[a]=False` for all of the symbols before using Solve. Going back and forth repeatedly, even using a map function, is annoying. To solve the issue, I created a new function defined by `numeric[x_Symbol]=True; numeric[x_?NumericQ]=True; numeric[___]=False;`. The issue with this method is that I want `numeric[b+5]` to evaluate as True. For example, when you type `NumericQ[c]=True; NumericQ[c + 7];` evaluates to True. Initially, I added a line for every operation between symbols that I wanted to be True --`Plus[x_?numeric,y_?numeric]=True`. Even just adding Plus made the code significantly slower, but adding it for all of the operations - Times, Conjugate, Exponent - made it too slow to evaluate. My code makes extensive use of NumericQ, so I need whatever I use to not be much slower than it if I want it to run in a reasonable time. Thank you for the help.

**Edit**: The reason I want to do this is I am trying to add commutative properties like distributive to NonCommutativeMultiply. The NonCommutativeAlgebra package does this, but the symbols that I want to be noncommutative (one's with a subscript) are commutative in this package. Combining NumericQ with assigning certain symbols as numeric implements what I am wanting to do perfectly, but I have to change those symbols back to not numeric if I want to use the solve function.

Comment: If every symbol is numeric, and any composition of numeric things is also numeric, what exactly is not numeric? Can you give an example of things you don't want to consider to be numeric? Also, can you be a bit more specific as to what you need all those checks for?

Comment: Can you clarify how it interferes with `Solve`? I hope you are not doing `NumericQ[a] = True` then try to `Solve` for `a`, as that makes no sense. If you _are_ doing that, then why do you want `NumericQ[a]` to be `True`? It only really makes sense to set `NumericQ[a]` to `True` if you also set `N[a]`, so `a` truly behaves like a numeric constant.

Comment: Why not use `a[1]` and give `a` the `NumericFunction` attribute?

Comment: Overall, this feels like an XY problem: https://xyproblem.info/ More clarifications are needed. I suggest you explain the actual task you want to complete instead of asking about how to implement a solution which is very likely not the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. This is my first time using Mathematica, so I am not sure what all of the best practices are, I have just been focused on writing something that works. I am trying to write a program similar to NCAlgebra that gives NonCommutativeMultiply certain properties like the distributive property and bringing commutative elements (numbers and symbols) to the front. @LukasLang Elements that are not commutative have a subscript. For example, ```Subscript[S,1]``` or ```Subscript[U,2]```. (The NCAlgebra package treats these as commutative.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I am getting the program to work right now by doing what you are saying, setting ```NumericQ[a] = True``` then later when I want to solve for a, I set ```NumericQ[a] = False```. I am using NumericQ as a shortcut to check for elements that I want to commute with NonCommutativeMultiply because of how quickly it runs even if I add symbols that should also be commutative.

Comment: Does the noncommutative algebra that you're interested in only have a finite (or clearly defined) list of noncommuting elements? Then you can define `CentralQ` as in my answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165511/29926 , which allows for commuting quantities including symbolic functions and so on

Comment: @LukasLang Technically speaking infinities are not numeric... :)

Answer (score 0):

In [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) you can use subscripts with noncommutative symbols.

```
SNC[X]
a ** Subscript[X, 1] ** b
```

evaluates to

> a ** Subscript[X, 1] ** b

as you would expect. Subscripted symbols inherit the noncommutative property from their base symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding definitions to `Plus`, `Times` etc, which slows everything down tremendously, it should be more efficient to keep the logic in the definition of your numeric test, which I named `myNumericQ` here. I also include the last line to show how it can be used to make some symbols "numeric".

```
ClearAll[myNumericQ]
myNumericQ[expr_?NumericQ] := True;
myNumericQ[(Plus | Times | Power |
      head_ /; MemberQ[Attributes[head], NumericFunction])[args___]] := 
  And @@ myNumericQ /@ {args};
myNumericQ[arg_] = False;
myNumericQ[n] = True;
```